# Where should I add in my alertdialog and how to get the value in the json?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Tutorial link used: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Problem is:
I have a working login and sign up activity for my application. However, I want to prompt an alert dialog after users click the login/sign up button to show some information.

I followed the tutorial link above and created the AlertDialogManager.java.
This is my code for the Login button:

```
try{                                                
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            //String message = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            //Log.v("SignUp", "Checkpoint 3");


            if (success == 1) {
                session.createLoginSession(email);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
                startActivity (i);

                finish();
            }else{
                //failed to login                   
            }
        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I tried adding the alertdialog code in the section when the application failed to log the user in. My alertdialog code:

```
alert.showAlertDialog(Login.this,"Login failed", "Bla bla bla", false);
```

Whenever I tried click the log in button, the whole application crashed and show me the logcat below:

```
05-15 10:08:55.641: W/dalvikvm(2338): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-15 10:08:55.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2338): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-15 10:08:55.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2338): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-15 10:08:55.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2338):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
05-15 10:08:55.701: E/AndroidRuntime(2338): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

I am still quite new to Android programming >< so can someone please help me out? Thanks! Tell me anything else you all need and I will post it up here.

Entire code is as below:
public class Login extends Activity {

```
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

//Alert dialog manager
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

//Session manager
SessionManager session;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText C_Email;
EditText C_Password;

public static final String DOMAIN = "192.168.0.112"; //Home
//public static final String DOMAIN = "172.18.74.146";
//URL to login
private static String url_login = "http://" + DOMAIN + "/iChop/login.php";

//JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
//private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    //Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    //Edit Text
    C_Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.C_Email);
    C_Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.C_Password);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Login Status: " + session.isLoggedIn(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //Login button
    Button Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Login);

    //Button click event
    Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new customer in background
            new CustomerLogin().execute();
        }
    });

}


class CustomerLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Logging you in!");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args){
        String email = C_Email.getText().toString();
        String password = C_Password.getText().toString();

        //Building parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        /**
        Log.d("C_Email", email);
        Log.d("C_Password", password);
        **/

        //getting JSON object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_login, "POST", params);
        Log.v("SignUp", "Checkpoint 1");

        //check log cat for response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
        Log.v("SignUp", "Checkpoint 2");

        //check for success tag
        try{                                                
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            //String message = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            //Log.v("SignUp", "Checkpoint 3");


            if (success == 1) {
                session.createLoginSession(email);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
                startActivity (i);

                finish();
            }else{
                //failed to login

            }
        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return true;
}

public void SignUp (View view) {
    Intent signup = new Intent (this, SignUp.class);
    startActivity(signup);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are calling the Intent and the alert dialog in `doInBackground`, you need to probably call the Intent or the alert dialog in `OnPostExceute`.

Try executing this in your OnPostExecute

```
if (success == 1) {
                session.createLoginSession(email);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
                startActivity (i);

                finish();
            }else{
                alert.showAlertDialog(Login.this,"Login failed", "Bla bla bla", false);

            }
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi @Oam, I tried it your way, it shows the alert dialog box! But what if I want to set the message according to how i receive the response from the JSON? Something like this: {"success":0,"message":"Please fill in all the fields!"}

Comment: Save the message string in `doInBackground` and pass that string in your `showAlertDialog` method as the parameter.

Comment: in doInBackground, I wrote String message = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);.... but when I use the message in onPostExecute...it shows error (cannot be resolved to a variable)

Comment: make that `message` string as a global variable. Declare it before `onCreate`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you create this Dialog from a thread that is not the UI thread, for example an AsyncTask. Dialogs must be shown from the UI thread. Let your AsyncTask report back to the Activity where it was started from if the Login was sucessful or not, then show your Dialog :)

Edit: 
You AsyncTask currently returns a `String` but that is always `null` so you obviously don't return anything. Let you AsyncTask return a Boolean for 'success' (wether die Login was successfull or not). 
Change `CustomerLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>` to `CustomerLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean>` and return a boolean for the success of the login (instead of a `null` `String` which you do right now). You then can use this bolean in `onPostExecute` which again runs on the UI thread, you can create you dialog from there.

Comment: @Ascorbin...thanks for the swift answer...but how should I do that?

Comment: I am confused when i reached "return a boolean for the success of the login (instead of a null String which you do right now). You then can use this bolean in onPostExecute which again runs on the UI thread, you can create you dialog from there." Can you clear me out?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in `button.setOnClickListener()`

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() { // This thread runs in the UI
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                         // Update the UI, call your asynctask
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();
    }
```

Comment: I am having problem at the handler ... it shows error there @@

Comment: erm...a red line under the handler

Comment: Did you define handler variable ?

Comment: erm...nope >< how shud i define it?

Comment: Handler handler; // as global variable